# Include external library depending on Android API level

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, admob

I need to include two different external libraries depending on API level. Is there any way to include it this way to link library dynamically?

Thank in Advance..

Comment: "I need to include two different external libraries depending on API level" -- why?

Comment: Actually I am trying upgrade admob SDK in my app..Its working fine on 2.x devices..But its crashing in a strange way in 1.6 devices also ad is scrollable in 1.6..But dint faced such issue while using older admob sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check de sdk version and call a diferent class dependint on the outcome

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 4) (for 1.6 )

Answer (score 0):

The new Android Market supports [multiple-apk](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html) that is the perfect solution for you, you can build different app depending by your sdk target...